# How to send images in Gitter?

Tags: markdown, instant-messaging

The format shown in the help of gitter.im is `![alt](http://)`, which solves the problem of including images from external websites, but not how to send images that are not already on a website. Does this mean we have to upload the image somewhere and then paste the link in this format, or is there a way to send the image directly through gitter.im?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Right, that is [markdown syntax](https://gitter.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/200176682-Markdown-basics) for creating a link to an image. You can use your own website, or a service imgur, or dropbox, or google photos, etc, to hold the images.

Comment: it's not necessary to upload first on web then do it. it's simple method on gitter is drag and drop method which you can upload or sent chat message image easily without any upload image on web